# css pseudo code with one before to recreate the featured mockup

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I was tasked with a challenge by a developer to receate this comp with one :before pseudo element and found it outside of my relm of experience, I didn't end up solving the problem but as stated I did manage to recreate the comp with two pseudo element on one selector.  Here is a jsfiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/rt9nbg8j/

```
body{
width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

h1:before{
    border-top:1px solid gray;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    height:60px;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    background:#fff;
}



 h1{
    height:60px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ccc;
   /* border:1px solid red; */
    width:100%;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:arial;
    line-height:4em;
}

h1:after{
    border-top:1px solid gray;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    height:60px;
    width:25%;
    float:right;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: What comp? Also, you should move your code into your post as an embedded snippet.

Comment: The comp is essentially what I created, except I was told to only use the :before line.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I know it's a weird question I was asked to do this in an interview with live code and I couldn't think of it. So this is helpful for those who may get this I the future, but I personally agree it's a bit of a far out question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 4em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  position: relative;
}
h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
```

Comment: Simillar than yours so I prefer not to make it as an answer. http://jsfiddle.net/rt9nbg8j/2/ Basically you can use 100% width for the pseudolement if you don't use position:relative to the h1.

Comment: Yes, but mine is dynamic to the height of the h1 :)

Comment: and that's why I love (sometimes) my job. So many ways to go. If there were not deathlines It would be perfect. And keep up the good work. Your name and "web-tiki" always comes in mind when thinking about how much I have been learning from this web (in my type of job).

Answer (score 0):

### A perfect replica

The solution is to set the title using the `:before` pseudo-element's `content` property.

***Caveat:*** This is a poor solution for use in the real world. If this challenge (with its seemingly arbitrary restriction) represents a real-world use case, I suggest refactoring your HTML or CSS to allow for the use of additional markup and/or pseudo-elements or settling for an imperfect (but good enough) replication of the comp.

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    background: #fff;
}
h1:before {
    content: 'Testing this title';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: 25%;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: bold 16px/60px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
```

**Update:** *(just for funsies)*

If I were to be literal and true to the challenge to "receate this comp with one `:before` pseudo element", I would not use any html element other than the de facto `body` tag.

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    background: #fff;
}
body:before {
    content: 'Testing this title';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: 25%;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: bold 16px/60px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but of course the `content` property shouldn't *actually* contain content as it is intended for styling.

Comment: The OP's challenge: "receate this comp with one `:before` pseudo element." There are no other conditions. From a challenge stand point, I perfectly replicated the comp.

Comment: Not disputing the creation but if it can't/shouldn't be used in the real world that deserves a caveat comment at least. No solution is perfect...they all have flaws.

Comment: The fact that this is a "challenge" with an arbitrary restriction implies that it isn't intended for use in the real world. I assumed this was a bit like a code golf type question. And you're right: my solution isn't perfect (I never claimed it was), just my replication of the comp. But I'll concede that a caveat is a welcome addition to my answer.